# applicationDidFinishLaunching - not triggering

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSRunAlertPanel(@"", @"", @"", @"", @"");
}
```

I have this, just to test it out, and for some reason, the NSRunAlertPanel is not triggering after the app starts...this is a problem because there are many "init" things that are necessary for my app to run.

Are there any other ways of doing this? why is this happening?

Comment: Is this in a class that implements the NSApplicatonDelegate protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this comment on antoher forum about this:

Are you sure applicationDidFinishLaunching runs? I.e. did you actually connect your app delegate object to the delegate outlet of File's Owner (or Application)?

Also found another forum posting where the author just did a clean to clear out old artifacts and it started to work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Clean. It clears out the build directory so there are no left over artifacts from the previous build.