# applicationDidFinishLaunching not called, using storyboards and swift3

Tags: cocoa, swift3, xcode-storyboard

The `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not being called when I run my app.

This is the code of my `AppDelegate` class:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSSquareStatusItemLength)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

I am using *Swift 3* and *storyboards* for my app.

The answer to [applicationDidFinishLaunching - not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903096/applicationdidfinishlaunching-not-triggering) suggests to connect `AppDelegate.swift` to application object in storyboard. I don't have any application object there.

My app does not have main menu, it is *agent*, as I am trying to build something similar to spotlight.

What should I do to get `applicationDidFinishLaunching` running?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even if your app is running as an agent your storyboard is supposed to have this structure:

[image]

If not, drag a blue cube (object) into the application scene, set the class of the object to `AppDelegate` and control-drag from `Application` to `App Delegate` and select `delegate`.

If you even have no Application Scene, create a new project with storyboard enabled, delete your current Main.storyboard file and drag the Main.storyboard of the new created project into your current project.

Comment: Thanks! I really missed the Application Scene.

Comment: How to make it without storyboard programmatically?

Comment: @fnc12 You have to set the delegate in `main` right before `run`ning the app