# User Defaults is not registering new keys?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode8

I'm designing an app (iOS) and I'm trying to use UserDefaults (Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3). I had previously added some keys and values which were working fine.

However, when I added some more keys, the old keys were still working but the new keys were not working. Specifically, the new keys were returning 0 whenever I tried to read them.

I have searched Google and SO for ages and still can't find where I'm going wrong.

Please help!

**In AppDelegate.swift**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let d = UserDefaults.standard

    let defaultValues = ["highScore"  : 0,
                         "second"     : 0,
                         "third"      : 0,
                         "balls"      : 0,
                         "maxLives"   : 5,
                         "increaseML" : 250]

    d.register(defaults: defaultValues)

}
```

**In MenuScene.swift (custom class)**

```
var maxLives = defaults.integer(forKey: "maxLives")
var increaseML = defaults.integer(forKey: "increaseML")
```

For some reason, `increaseML` and `maxLives` are returning 0 even though I set their values to be 250 and 5 respectively.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that no defaults were saved for those keys?

Comment: Defaults are saved for all but 'maxLives' and 'increaseML'. All of the others are working fine.

Comment: According to the apple documentation about `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`, that method shouldn't be used. Use 
`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` instead.

Comment: What does `print(d.object(forKey: "maxLives") as Any)` print?

Comment: @MartinR It prints nil. If I try print(defaults.integer(forKey: "maxLives")), it prints 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not invoked. It could be caused, if you are using `Storyboards`, that your `Appdelegate` is not hooked up properly.

You can fix it following this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472371/applicationdidfinishlaunching-not-called-using-storyboards-and-swift3) or move the initialisation of your defaults to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

what will be called every time the application launches.

Also, Apple even discourages you from using `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623053-applicationdidfinishlaunching).

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong, but I thought applicationDidFinishLaunching is invoked when the app is installed. If I follow your suggestion, doesn't that mean my values will be **reset** to these values every time I launch the app? As I'm changing these values in-game, these values are **not** supposed to reset every launch.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel read the DOCUMENTATION: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623053-applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: @AdityaChaurasia not necessarily, it is a not yet, but will be soon deprecated API. Apple urges you to use the function i have posted about.

Comment: @dirtydanee I'll try what you've suggested

Comment: @AdityaChaurasia i have just read you edited comment. I will update my answer soon to avoid overriding.

Comment: @dirtydanee I have tried your suggestion by moving my declarations into the func application(...) and I think it works ; ). Can't believe it was that simple ... thanks!

Comment: It will override every time you start the app. I will update my answer in a minute with a check to overcome on the overriding.

Comment: @dirtydanee I don't think it overrides as I have deleted and reinstalled the app, changed a few values in-game, closed the simulator, launched it again, and (surprisingly) the values **are** retained. In case it helps, I'm not using storyboards and I'm working purely in .sks and .swift files

Comment: @AdityaChaurasia i was reading the documentation of `register`, i could not find anything that would suggests something like that. I have added a code snippet just in case, if your tests verify they are not being overriden, that it is even better! btw, very good first question, keep up the quality questions ;)

Comment: @dirtydanee Thanks! I've been using SO for over a year, but I've never had to ask a question! Shows how useful SO is!

Comment: @dirtydanee I'm not sure, but I don't think the boolean flag has any significance. Its purpose is to **avoid** overriding the values in the UserDefaults but it relies on the key "didRegisterDefaults" **not** being overridden!

Comment: yeah, but it is the engineers responsibility not to override the flag in any other places, just here. But as your tests suggested, you do not need it, right?

Comment: The implementation of `didRegisterDefaults` is completely wrong. It's intended to call `registerDefaults` every time when the application launches. The method does **never** override any key / value pair. Only if the application removes the key or the entire preference file then calling `registerDefaults` recreates the key with the default value.  And do not call `synchronize()` after `registerDefaults`. It has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

let d = UserDefaults.standard

```
let defaultValues = ["highScore"  : 0,
                     "second"     : 0,
                     "third"      : 0,
                     "balls"      : 0,
                     "maxLives"   : 5,
                     "increaseML" : 250]

d.register(defaults: defaultValues)
d.synchronize()
```